# How can I increase node size on dragging in GOjs?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I'm using GOjs to create nodes and to connect them with each other just like a flow diagram.
I have two div. In the first div (id="NodesContainer") I'm creating go.Palette and by using the id of second div (id="myDiagram") I'm designing the nodes on calling of Init() method in javascript. You can see in code block.
All I want is, When I drag the nodes into the second div, the nodes should become bigger in size.
Please help me if you know the answer.

```
        //initialize the Palette that is on the top side of the page
    NodesContainer =
  $(go.Palette, "NodesContainer",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
    {
        //"animationManager.duration": 800, // slightly longer than default (600ms) animation
        nodeTemplateMap: myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap,  // share the templates used by myDiagram
        model: new go.GraphLinksModel([  // specify the contents of the Palette
          { category: "START", img: "../../Content/images/Start_Node.png" },
          { category: "END", img: "../../Content/images/End_Node.png" },
          { category: "ConnectorIn", img: "../../Content/images/Connector_In_Node.png" },
          { category: "ConnectorOut", img: "../../Content/images/Connector_Out_Node.png" },
          { category: "Comment", img: "../../Content/images/Comment_Node.png" },
          { category: "DECISION", img: "../../Content/images/Decision_Node.png" },
          { category: "Execution", img: "../../Content/images/Custom_Execution_Node.png" }

        ])
    });
    //end of Initialize the Palette that is on the top side of the page


    function initNodes() {
    var vargojsshapetextsize = [];
    if (window.goSamples) goSamples();
    function nodeStyle() {
        return [
          // The Node.location comes from the "loc" property of the node data,
          // converted by the Point.parse static method.
          // If the Node.location is changed, it updates the "loc" property of the node data,
          // converting back using the Point.stringify static method.
          new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
          {
              // the Node.location is at the center of each node
              locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
              //isShadowed: true,
              //shadowColor: "#888",
              // handle mouse enter/leave events to show/hide the ports
              mouseEnter: function (e, obj) { showPorts(obj.part, true); },
              mouseLeave: function (e, obj) { showPorts(obj.part, false); }
          }
        ];
    }
    // Define a function for creating a "port" that is normally transparent.
    function makePort(name, spot, output, input) {
        // the port is basically just a small circle that has a white stroke when it is made visible
        return $(go.Shape, "Circle",
                 {
                     fill: "transparent",
                     stroke: null,  // this is changed to "white" in the showPorts function
                     desiredSize: new go.Size(8, 8),
                     alignment: spot,
                     alignmentFocus: spot,  // align the port on the main Shape
                     portId: name,  // declare this object to be a "port"
                     fromSpot: spot,
                     toSpot: spot,  // declare where links may connect at this port
                     fromLinkable: output,
                     toLinkable: input,  // declare whether the user may draw links to/from here
                     fromLinkableDuplicates: true,
                     toLinkableDuplicates: true,
                     fromMaxLinks: 1,
                     toMaxLinks: 1,// declare whether the user may draw links to/from here
                     cursor: "pointer"  // show a different cursor to indicate potential link point
                 });
    }

    // Make link labels visible if coming out of a "conditional" node.
    // This listener is called by the "LinkDrawn" and "LinkRelinked" DiagramEvents.
    function showLinkLabel(e) {
        var label = e.subject.findObject("LABEL");
        if (label !== null)
            label.visible = (e.subject.fromNode.data.figure === "Diamond");
    }



    var $ = go.GraphObject.make; // for conciseness in defining templates

    myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagram", // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
    {
        initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.TopCenter,
        allowDrop: true, // must be true to accept drops from the Palette
        initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center, //For Allignment
        "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
        //allowResize:true,
        "LinkDrawn": showLinkLabel, // this DiagramEvent listener is defined below
        "LinkRelinked": showLinkLabel,
        "animationManager.duration": 1200, // slightly longer than default (600ms) animation
        "undoManager.isEnabled": true   // enable undo & redo
    });

    // define the Node templates for regular nodes
    var lightText = 'whitesmoke';

    myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("START",
      $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
           $(go.Picture,
            {
                maxSize: new go.Size(30, 30)
            },
           new go.Binding("source", "img"))
        ),
        // One named port, at the bottom side, all output only:
        makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
      ));

    myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("END",
      $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
           $(go.Picture,
            {
                maxSize: new go.Size(30, 30)
            },
           new go.Binding("source", "img"))
        ),
        // three named ports, one on each side except the bottom, all input only:
        makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
        makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, false, true),
        makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, false, true)
      ));
    myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Execution",
      $(go.Node, "Spot", nodeStyle(),
        // the main object is a Panel that surrounds a TextBlock with a rectangular Shape
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
           $(go.Picture,
            {
                maxSize: new go.Size(30, 30)
            },
           new go.Binding("source", "img"))
        ),
        // four named ports, one on each side:
        makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
        makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, true),
        makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, true),
        makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false)
      ));
}
```

//End of Init()
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F8m3.png)

Comment: To see the image plz click above on "enter image description here"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy thing to do is to set the **Palette.initialScale** to a value smaller than 1.0.  That way the items in the palette look smaller than the nodes after being dropped in the main diagram.

An alternative to really change the size (in document coordinates) is to implement an "ExternalObjectsDropped" **DiagramEvent** listener than runs through the `e.subject`, which will be a GoJS collection, to actually modify the size of each Node.

Comment: Hello Walter Northwoods, thanks for your quick reply. I'm new on Gojs, so it will be a great help if could show the code to set Palette.initialScale. So that node icons in my upper div(NodesContainer) will look small and when I drag them to the bottom div(myDiagram), then become bigger in size.

Please help me out.

Comment: If you search the samples you will find a few examples. https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/search?q=initialScale&type=Code

Comment: Thanks a lot Walter Northwoods, this is working like a charm. I've set initialscale as follows-
$(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
{
    initialScale: 1.5,
}


Well is it also possible to append text at the bottom of each node on dragging, (Actually I want bigger node with custom texts at bottom). Now I'm getting bigger nodes, I just want to append text too on dragging.
Please let me know.

Comment: You can customize the selection Adornment to include whatever you want.  Or you can customize your node template to be whatever you want, if you want that information to be available at any time, not only when the node is selected.

Comment: Adornments are bound to the same data object as the adorned Node, so data bindings will work.

Comment: Hi Walter, Sorry I dint get your point. Can you please show me some examples so that I can append text at the bottom on node when I drag it. 
It will be great help if you can share some code.

Comment: I really don't know what you want to do -- there are so many plausible interpretations of your requirements.

Comment: Hi, I've already done this. Can you please help me, how can i move left and right ports to little bit upper side. 
It is like when I create a node in vertical panel(to have a text at the bottom of node), I make ports in L,R,T & B directions. But because of this text, the left and right ports are visible at little bottom side instead of middle of the node image. So how can I move left and right ports to some upper side????

Comment: This seems to be a new topic.  It would be helpful to provide a screenshot for what you have done and a screenshot or sketch for what you want instead.

Comment: I'm not able to add a screen shot here. Give me your email Id please. or should I put it below in "Answer Your Question" section.

Comment: Hey Walter, I've added the snapshot you asked for in following answer. Please click on "i want this" in following answer to see the image.